# Google Cloud Storage bucket items and FTP

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Two fold question: 
1) Does google have a solution to allow third party clients to FTP into a Cloud Storage Bucket and get objects?

2) If this is not possible, what is the best way to sync items in a cloud storage bucket with an FTP Server?